# как сериализировать json, если формат List<List<List<Map<String,String>>>>?

Tags: flutter, dart

я получаю данные в формате:

```
[
  [
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ]
  ]
]
```

как правильно этот json сериализировать правильно чтобы не падал производительность?

использовал следующий способ но при получении большого количества данных производительность сильно падает:

```
class MapData {
  final String a;
  final String b;
  final String c;
  MapData({this.a, this.b, this.c});
}
```

при `initState` использовал это:

```
var allData = json.decode(widget.data);
    var myData = List<List<List<MapData>>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {
      myData.add([]);
      for (int i0 = 0; i0 < allData[i].length; i0++) {
        myData[i].add([]);
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < allData[i][i0].length; i1++) {
          var record = MapData(
              a: allData[i][i0][i1]['a'],
              b: allData[i][i0][i1]['b'],
              c: allData[i][i0][i1]['c'],);
          myData[i][i0].add(record);
        }
      }
    }
```

я использую все данные из этого формата json, то есть `List(вертикальный список)<List(горизонтальный список внутри вертикального списка)<List(еще один список внутри горизонтального списка)<Map<String,String>(отображаемые данные внитри списка)>>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Желательно такие тяжёлые вещи выносить в отдельные [isolate](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a). И тройной цикл всегда будет долгим, здесь уже ничего не сделаешь...

Даже не представляю для чего это нужно, но вот:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  print("Start 1");

  List<List<List<MapData>>> temp = mapDataFromJson("""
  [
  [
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      },
      {
        "a": "1",
        "b": "2",
        "c": "3"
      }
    ]
  ]
]
  """);

  print(temp[0][0][0].a);

  print("Start 2");

  temp.forEach((x) => x.forEach((y) => y.forEach((z) => print(z.b))));
}

List<List<List<MapData>>> mapDataFromJson(String str) =>
    List<List<List<MapData>>>.from(json.decode(str).map(
          (x) => List<List<MapData>>.from(x.map(
            (x) => List<MapData>.from(
              x.map((x) => MapData.fromJson(x)),
            ),
          )),
        ));

String mapDataToJson(List<List<List<MapData>>> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(
      data.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(
            x.map((x) => List<dynamic>.from(
                  x.map((x) => x.toJson()),
                )),
          )),
    ));

class MapData {
  final String a;
  final String b;
  final String c;

  MapData({
    this.a,
    this.b,
    this.c,
  });

  factory MapData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MapData(
        a: json["a"],
        b: json["b"],
        c: json["c"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "a": a,
        "b": b,
        "c": c,
      };
}
```

Comment: рисую музыкальные ноты, первый list такты, второй list размер одного такта, третий list сколько в одной секции помещается map, а map в свою очередь ноты(т.е табы)

Comment: a isolate можно использовать уже загруженным json файлом?

Comment: @KizatSuleimenov да, но там передача данных через сообщения. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing 
https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/01/futures-isolates-event-loop/