# Flutter API post

Tags: flutter, dart

есть пост запрос
пример:

```
POST /api HTTP/1.1
Host: checkout.test.paycom.com
X-Auth: 100fe486b33784292111b7dc
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
    "id": 123,
    "method": "cards.create",
    "params": {
        "card": { "number": "4444444444444444", "expire": "0420"},
        "amount": 350000,
        "save": true
    }
}
```

функция:

```
class Service {

 static String url = 'checkout.test.paycom.com';
  static Map<String, dynamic> headers = {
    'Host': 'checkout.test.paycom.com',
    'X-Auth': '3423343243434',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  };

  Future createCard(
      String id, String cardNumber, String expire, int amount) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = {
        'id': id,
        'method': 'cards.create',
        'params': {
          'card': {
            'number': cardNumber,
            'expire': expire,
          },
          'amount': amount,
        },
      };
      final response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final result = jsonDecode(response.body);
        List<CardModel> data = result['params']['card'];

        print(data);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }
}


 factory CardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
return CardModel(
  id: json['id'],
  cardNumber: json['number'],
  expire: json['expire'],
  amount: int.parse(json['amount']),
);
```

}

выдает ошибку  type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast. Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ с сервера парстие не правильно (чтобы это руками не писать есть: [сайт](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=dart), [плагин VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BendixMa.dart-data-class-generator), [плагин AS](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12429-dart-data-class), [кодоген](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries)):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() {
  Service s = Service();
  s.createCard("123", "4444444444444444" , "0420", 350000);
}

class Service {
  static String url = 'checkout.test.paycom.com';
  static Map<String, dynamic> headers = {
    'Host': 'checkout.test.paycom.com',
    'X-Auth': '3423343243434',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  };

  Future createCard(String id, String cardNumber, String expire, int amount) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = {
        'id': id,
        'method': 'cards.create',
        'params': {
          'card': {
            'number': cardNumber,
            'expire': expire,
          },
          'amount': amount,
          'save': true
        },
      };
      final response = await http.post(url, body: body, headers: headers);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        CardModel data = CardModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

        print(data.result.card.token);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
    return null;
  }
}

class CardModel {
    CardModel({
        this.jsonrpc,
        this.id,
        this.result,
    });

    final String jsonrpc;
    final int id;
    final Result result;

    factory CardModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CardModel(
        jsonrpc: json["jsonrpc"] == null ? null : json["jsonrpc"],
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        result: json["result"] == null ? null : Result.fromJson(json["result"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "jsonrpc": jsonrpc == null ? null : jsonrpc,
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "result": result == null ? null : result.toJson(),
    };
}

class Result {
    Result({
        this.card,
    });

    final Card card;

    factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
        card: json["card"] == null ? null : Card.fromJson(json["card"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "card": card == null ? null : card.toJson(),
    };
}

class Card {
    Card({
        this.number,
        this.expire,
        this.token,
        this.recurrent,
        this.verify,
    });

    final String number;
    final String expire;
    final String token;
    final bool recurrent;
    final bool verify;

    factory Card.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Card(
        number: json["number"] == null ? null : json["number"],
        expire: json["expire"] == null ? null : json["expire"],
        token: json["token"] == null ? null : json["token"],
        recurrent: json["recurrent"] == null ? null : json["recurrent"],
        verify: json["verify"] == null ? null : json["verify"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "number": number == null ? null : number,
        "expire": expire == null ? null : expire,
        "token": token == null ? null : token,
        "recurrent": recurrent == null ? null : recurrent,
        "verify": verify == null ? null : verify,
    };
}
```

---

[Как парсить array из json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1131054/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-array-%D0%B8%D0%B7-json/1131091#1131091)

[Как сериализировать json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1104818/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-listlistlistmapstring-string/1105144#1105144)

Comment: Сайт который вы дали Кодоген, нужно всегда вставлять пример ответа API?

Comment: @AndreyKhan если модели одинаковые, то можно использовать которые есть. Если разные то под каждый ответ делать свою модель.

Comment: CardModel data = CardModel.fromJson(json.decode(str)) вместо str я должен вписать response.body?

Comment: @AndreyKhan да, не увидел...

Comment: все равно выдает ошибку type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>', но если сделать хот релоад то уже выдает ошибку сервера

Comment: @AndreyKhan добавьте конкретный ответ сервера (с заменой личных данных на другие), до сериализации в вопрос. Его получить можно так: `print(response.body);`

Comment: на `print(response.body);` ничего не выдает, сразу же появляется type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast. если же убрать `params`  в `body` то принтует ответ {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"message":"Parse error.","code":-32700,"data":{}}}.

Comment: @AndreyKhan пройдитесь отладчиком кода. Возможно вам приходит не ответ сервера, а ошибка. https://www.google.com/url?q=https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwi_jvPP_pfqAhVJxKYKHSH6CZcQFjAAegQICBAB&usg=AOvVaw2Dermfs3x3MJU4WyPbUKxH https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.r5am.ru/content/Programs/howto/howto-intellij-idea-debugging.html&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjSjO_5_pfqAhU1xcQBHbiHCMUQFjADegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw048pWjSIx39_BzCL_NkgYC