# Парсинг сложного json flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

Помогите разобраться с парсингом сложного `json` файла

```
    "count": 82,
    "next": "http://swapi.dev/api/people/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "name": "Luke Skywalker",
            "height": "172",
            "mass": "77",
            "hair_color": "blond",
            "skin_color": "fair",
            "eye_color": "blue",
            "birth_year": "19BBY",
            "gender": "male",
            "homeworld": "http://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/",
            "films": [
                "http://swapi.dev/api/films/1/",
                "http://swapi.dev/api/films/2/",
                "http://swapi.dev/api/films/3/",
                "http://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"
            ],
            "species": [],
            "vehicles": [
                "http://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/14/",
                "http://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/30/"
            ],
            "starships": [
                "http://swapi.dev/api/starships/12/",
                "http://swapi.dev/api/starships/22/"
            ],
            "created": "2014-12-09T13:50:51.644000Z",
            "edited": "2014-12-20T21:17:56.891000Z",
            "url": "http://swapi.dev/api/people/1/"
        } 
   ]
}
```

Код на  `flutter`:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<List<Character>> fetchCharacters(http.Client client) async {
  final response =
  await client.get('http://swapi.dev/api/people/');
  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parseCharacter, response.body);
}

// A function that converts a response body into a List<Photo>.
List<Character> parseCharacter(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
  return parsed.map<Character>((json) => Character.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Character {
  final String name;
  final int height;
  final int mass;
  final String hairColor;
  final String skinColor;
  Character({this.name, this.height, this.mass, this.hairColor, this.skinColor});
  factory Character.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Character(
      name: json['name'] as String,
      height: json['height'] as int,
      mass: json['mass'] as int,
      hairColor: json['hair_color'] as String,
      skinColor: json['skin_color'] as String,
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Isolate Demo';
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Character>>(
        future: fetchCharacters(http.Client()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? PhotosList(character: snapshot.data)
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PhotosList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Character> character;
  PhotosList({Key key, this.character}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: character.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          elevation: 5,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(
                character[index].name,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Вопрос в том, как мне исправить код, чтобы брать данные из запроса, начиная с массива `"results":`

Comment: `return parsed["results"].map<Character>((json) => Character.fromJson(json)).toList();` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1142227/flutter-api-post/1142313#1142313

Comment: ```I/flutter (30288): Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance method 'cast' with matching arguments.
I/flutter (30288): Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:4
I/flutter (30288): Tried calling: cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
I/flutter (30288): Found: cast<RK, RV>() => Map<RK, RV> ```

Comment: `final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody) as Map<String, dynamic>;`

Comment: `Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Прочтите этот ответ.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1142227/flutter-api-post/1142313#1142313)

```
List<Character> parseCharacter(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = jsonDecode(responseBody) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  return parsed["results"].map<Character>((json) => Character.fromJson(json)).toList();
}

class Character {
    Character({
        this.name,
        this.height,
        this.mass,
        this.hairColor,
        this.skinColor,
        this.eyeColor,
        this.birthYear,
        this.gender,
        this.homeworld,
        this.films,
        this.species,
        this.vehicles,
        this.starships,
        this.created,
        this.edited,
        this.url,
    });

    final String name;
    final String height;
    final String mass;
    final String hairColor;
    final String skinColor;
    final String eyeColor;
    final String birthYear;
    final String gender;
    final String homeworld;
    final List<String> films;
    final List<dynamic> species;
    final List<String> vehicles;
    final List<String> starships;
    final DateTime created;
    final DateTime edited;
    final String url;

    factory Character.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Character(
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        height: json["height"] == null ? null : json["height"],
        mass: json["mass"] == null ? null : json["mass"],
        hairColor: json["hair_color"] == null ? null : json["hair_color"],
        skinColor: json["skin_color"] == null ? null : json["skin_color"],
        eyeColor: json["eye_color"] == null ? null : json["eye_color"],
        birthYear: json["birth_year"] == null ? null : json["birth_year"],
        gender: json["gender"] == null ? null : json["gender"],
        homeworld: json["homeworld"] == null ? null : json["homeworld"],
        films: json["films"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["films"].map((x) => x)),
        species: json["species"] == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(json["species"].map((x) => x)),
        vehicles: json["vehicles"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["vehicles"].map((x) => x)),
        starships: json["starships"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["starships"].map((x) => x)),
        created: json["created"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["created"]),
        edited: json["edited"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["edited"]),
        url: json["url"] == null ? null : json["url"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "height": height == null ? null : height,
        "mass": mass == null ? null : mass,
        "hair_color": hairColor == null ? null : hairColor,
        "skin_color": skinColor == null ? null : skinColor,
        "eye_color": eyeColor == null ? null : eyeColor,
        "birth_year": birthYear == null ? null : birthYear,
        "gender": gender == null ? null : gender,
        "homeworld": homeworld == null ? null : homeworld,
        "films": films == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(films.map((x) => x)),
        "species": species == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(species.map((x) => x)),
        "vehicles": vehicles == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(vehicles.map((x) => x)),
        "starships": starships == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(starships.map((x) => x)),
        "created": created == null ? null : created.toIso8601String(),
        "edited": edited == null ? null : edited.toIso8601String(),
        "url": url == null ? null : url,
    };
}
```