# Flutter vk api не берет изображение из постов

Tags: api, вконтакте, flutter

Есть вот такой виджет который должен собирать картинки из полученого json, но он этого не делает получаю ошибку такого вида ==> "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'"

Вот сам json:

attachments: [{type: photo, photo: {album_id: -7, date: 1596362998, id: 457247346, owner_id: 385816978, has_tags: false, access_key: 9e30b1caa3b4357560, sizes: [{height: 97, url: https://sun3-11.userapi.com/c854416/v854416163/248e8d/UG_xXtwLN0A.jpg, type: m, width: 130}, {height: 98, url: https://sun3-11.userapi.com/c854416/v854416163/248e92/bjapR9HUnRs.jpg, type: o, width: 130}, {height: 150, url: https://sun3-10.userapi.com/c854416/v854416163/248e93/MOem_w7iUw4.jpg, type: p, width: 200}, {height: 240, url: https://sun3-12.userapi.com/c854416/v854416163/248e94/7pqhTglIHqo.jpg, type: q, width: 320}, {height: 383, url: https://sun3-10.userapi.com/c854416/v854416163/248e95/SeRgzIkKj9Y.jpg, type: r, width: 510}, {height: 56, url: https://sun3-13.userapi.com/c854416/v854416163/248e8c/7_qDl9OcRCg.jpg, type: s, width: 75}, {height: 1920, url: https://sun3-11.userapi.com/c854416/v854416163/248e91/H8cR31BZUtg.jpg, type: w, width: 2560}, {height: 453, url: https://sun3-12.userapi.com/c854416/v854

Сам код(виджет):

```
Widget _buildImageColumn(dynamic item) => Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white54),
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
    child: Column(
      
      children: [
         new CachedNetworkImage(
           imageUrl: item['attachments']['photo']['sizes']['url'],
           placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
           errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
           fadeOutDuration: new Duration(seconds: 1),
           fadeInDuration: new Duration(seconds: 3),
         ),
        _buildRow(item)
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Но собирать изображения и так понятно что он не будет по одной простой причине что картинок много с разными разрешениями. Тогда я сделал как на Python

['attachments'][0]['photo']['sizes'][-1]['url']

там работало отлично, а тут не хочет знаки Flutter Help please

Какие аргументы передавать что бы получить нужное изображение?

---

На данный момент я разобрался с ошибкой которую я получаю, сейчас я не могу обработать ошибку которая ведет к красному экрану[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

Так может имеет смысл сериализировать ответ от сервера в объекты, и не писать магический код (я про `item['attachments']['photo']['sizes']['url']`)?

чтобы это руками не писать есть: [сайт](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=dart), [плагин VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BendixMa.dart-data-class-generator), [плагин AS](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12429-dart-data-class), [кодоген](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-using-code-generation-libraries)

---

[Как парсить array из json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1131054/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-array-%D0%B8%D0%B7-json/1131091#1131091)

[Как сериализировать json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1104818/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-listlistlistmapstring-string/1105144#1105144)

Comment: О боже не усложняйте мне жизнь. У меня уже полностью все готово, а вы меня просите сделать нечто совершенно новое для меня. На данный момент я разобрался с ошибкой которую я получаю, сейчас я не могу обработать  ошибку которая ведет к красному экрану

Comment: @sakol86 я вам наоборот пытаюсь облегчить жизнь) Опять же, вы боритесь с магией) Так и быть подскажу `attachments или sizes == null`, но чтобы не гадать придумали сериализацию в объекты.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, попробую сделать через сериализацию.