# undefined name in data file

Tags: flutter

выдает ошибку Undefined name 'acura_id'
Как я могу адаптировать этот код

```
class Brand {
  final String image, title;
  final int id;
  final List <String> subjects;

  final String acura_image, acura_title;
  final int acura_id;

  Brand({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.subjects,
    this.acura_id,
    this.acura_image,
    this.acura_title,
  });
}

List<Brand> brands = [
  Brand(
    id: 1,
    title: "ACURA",
    image: "images/acura-logo.png",
    subjects: [
      acura_id: 100,
      acura_title: "ILX",
      acura_image: "images/acura/ilx.png"
    ],
  ),
  Brand(
    id: 2,
    title: "ALFA ROMEO",
    image: "images/alfa-romeo-logo.png",
  ),
 ];
```

к этому

```
{
  "name": "Pooja",
  "majors":["CS", "Maths"],
  "subjects": [
    {
    "subjectName": "math",
    "teacher":"Ms S"
    },
    {
      "subjectName": "science",
      "teacher":"Ms P"
    }
    ]
}
```

мне нужно добавить еще списки к каждому списку

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Brand {
    Brand({
        this.name,
        this.majors,
        this.subjects,
    });

    final String name;
    final List<String> majors;
    final List<Subject> subjects;

    factory Brand.fromRawJson(String str) => Brand.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Brand.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Brand(
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        majors: json["majors"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["majors"].map((x) => x)),
        subjects: json["subjects"] == null ? null : List<Subject>.from(json["subjects"].map((x) => Subject.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "majors": majors == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(majors.map((x) => x)),
        "subjects": subjects == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(subjects.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Subject {
    Subject({
        this.subjectName,
        this.teacher,
    });

    final String subjectName;
    final String teacher;

    factory Subject.fromRawJson(String str) => Subject.fromJson(json.decode(str));

    String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

    factory Subject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Subject(
        subjectName: json["subjectName"] == null ? null : json["subjectName"],
        teacher: json["teacher"] == null ? null : json["teacher"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "subjectName": subjectName == null ? null : subjectName,
        "teacher": teacher == null ? null : teacher,
    };
}
```

---

[Как парсить array из json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1131054/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-array-%D0%B8%D0%B7-json/1131091#1131091)

[Как сериализировать json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1104818/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-json-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-listlistlistmapstring-string/1105144#1105144)

[Flutter API post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1142313/261617)

Comment: думаю я использую не совсем то, о чем вы подумали, могли бы вы посмотреть другой мой вопрос, связанный с этим, возможно, там я объяснился более изящно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165500/flutter-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8%d0%b7-data-file-%d0%b2-builder