# flutter как передавать информацию из data file в builder

Tags: flutter

у меня есть GridView.bulder, который строит GestureDetector's, при нажатии на каждый я перехожу Details с помощью [index]. В каждом из этих GestureDetector's есть также список с GestureDetector's, но здесь я не понимаю, как я могу открывать конкретный Data file, привязанный к изначальному [index], я пытался создать список в списке так

```
class Brand {
  final String image, title;
  final int id;
  final List <Subject> subjects;

  Brand({
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.title,
    this.subjects,
  });
}

class Subject {

  final int acura_id;
  final String acura_image, acura_title;

  Subject({
    this.acura_id,
    this.acura_image,
    this.acura_title,
  });
}

List<Brand> brands = [
  Brand(
    id: 1,
    title: "ACURA",
    image: "images/acura-logo.png",
    subjects: [
      Subject(
        acura_id: 1,
        acura_image: "images/acura/ilx.png",
        acura_title: "ILX"
      ),
      Subject(
        acura_id: 2,
        acura_image: "images/acura/rdx.png",
        acura_title: "RDX"
      ),
    ],
  ),
 ];
```

но при вызове `"${brand.subjects.acura_id}"` выдает ошибку **error: The getter 'acura_id' isn't defined for the type 'List'. (undefined_getter at [save_me] lib/cars_name.dart:43)**
Возможно, я использую не тот способ, если вы мне поможете понять почему я не могу вызвать список или подскажете на какой способ сменить код, буду благодарен

Comment: Вы обращаетесь к списку без индекса (надо делать так `brand.subjects[0].acura_id`). Приложите код с `GridView.bulder` и `Details`, я помогу передать индекс и решить проблему.

Comment: отредактировал вопрос, вставил код, который вы просили

Comment: я пробовал эту структуру до задания вопроса brand.subjects[0].acura_id. выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: кажется я решил проблему частично. как я могу перебрать все данные с помощью brand.subjects[0].acura_id? то есть чтобы колонки заполнялись самостоятельно по мере имеющихся данных

Comment: с помощью цикла ([for, foreach](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#for-loops)) или если вам нужны виджеты [List.generated](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.generate.html).

Comment: вопрос решен, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно было задать [index] вместо [0]